Shapes with simple distance functions.
Given a set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the distance function (DF) of $A$ is defined as
$$
\delta_A(\mathbf{x}) = \inf\{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|: \mathbf{y} \in A \}
$$
Some sets $A$ have a nice tidy closed-form DF. Here “tidy” means that the DF can be written as a formula involving a combination of elementary functions (like polynomials, roots, logs, trig functions and their inverses, etc.), or it can be computed in a program without resorting to iterative numerical methods. For reasons of my own, I want to exclude “min” and “max” from the list of allowed elementary functions. Examples: if $A$ is a circular disk or an infinite straight line, it obviously has a tidy DF. I was amazed to find out the other day that the same is true of the involute of a circle. Conversely, the DF of a (cubic) Bézier curve is not at all tidy.
My question: what other shapes have tidy DFs?
For bonus points: same question, but in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Obviously spheres, cylinders, cones and tori have tidy DFs. What else?
Why is this interesting? Because DFs are sometimes used to represent shapes in engineering & manufacturing, and computations are obviously easier if the DFs are tidy.

First of all, $A = DF^{-1}(0)$, so at least one requirement is that $A$ is the zero set of a tidy function.

Actually, I think $\delta_A^{-1}(0)$ is the closure of $A$. But I see your point. However, this is a pretty weak necessary condition. There are many cases of a set that’s the zero set of a tidy function but has a nasty DF. An elliptical region, for example.

One trick to generate more complex shapes is to notice that $\delta_{A\cup B}=\min(\delta_A,\delta_B)$. This allows you to recursively compute arbitrary unions.

@LPZ. Yes, and you can do set-theoretic intersections and subtractions by similar tricks. I meant to exclude min and max from my list of functions allowed in a “tidy” DF. I’ll change the question. Thanks.

@bubba Unfortunately, banning them is not that easy, since $\min(a, b)=(a+b)/2 - \left|(a-b)/2\right|$ and $\left|x\right|=\sqrt{x^2}$.

@PeterKošinár.  Hmm. Good point. Min and max enable boolean operations, so you can make compound objects that don’t much interest me. Not sure how to exclude them, though. Certainly don’t want to exclude square roots. Let’s see what I get.

Instead of the distance function you could consider its square and then do not allow radicals.

@MoisheKohan How would a tidy squared-DF look like for circle of radius $r$ with center at $(0,0)$ if radicals were not allowed?

@bubba How does the "obvious" tidy DF look like for circle (or disc; not sure if you intended it to be just the boundary or the inside too) of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0)$?

@PeterKošinár: It was a wrong idea. I do not think the question can be saved.
